# Git: Entering Password in Terminal Doesn't Work?

Tags: git, repository

I'm trying to push my newly committed project to GitHub via the terminal. For authentication, I enter my username just fine, but then it appears to freeze when I need to enter my password. I cant enter text or move the cursor. Hitting enter gives "Invalid username or password." because I didn't enter a password. Does anyone know what is going on here?

[Screen shot of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIHkH.png)

Comment: What remote URL are you using for the push operation (you can find out by running `git remote -v` in the terminal)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the shell (or the Terminal app in your case), when a program asks for a password (like git in this case), it **never** actually **shows your password** or shows you **typing your password** for security reasons (that way no one can see your password who's looking at your screen for example).

After entering your username, type your password (again the cursor *won't* move) then hit enter. If you entered the right password, then it will push to your remote on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

You may also need to create a Personal Access Token. This creates a token connected to your Github account that can be used with an API or CLI. Use this token rather than using your Github password.

See more in Github docs [here](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/managing-your-personal-access-tokens).

Answer (score -1):

The github username you should use is `git`, and you should add an ssh key. See [here](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/).

Comment: Using git as my username as is what I think your telling me to do didn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Creating an ssh key seems to be something good to do for the long run, but I'm just wanting to see that my repository is working.

Comment: You have to, there's no other way with github. It's how they work. Otherwise you'd need a shell account under your username on their server and they don't do that, they have 1 dedicated system account named `git`.

Comment: I made the SSH key and went through the authentication steps and it seemed to have worked. It's still asking me for my username and password though, how do I use the key?

Comment: You don't have to have an ssh key with github. You can use https and give your username and password. https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git/#next-steps-authenticating-with-github-from-git

Comment: @Kenney Also, there is **definitely** no "dedicated system account named `git`".

Comment: @TheSpurg do you work at github perhaps? Have you ever set up an SSH server?

Comment: @Kenney I don't work at GitHub, but I've used it for many years now. I've used both SSH and HTTPS to authenticate with GitHub. Additionally, I wasn't trying to say that somewhere on GitHub's *servers*, there's **not** a system user named `git`, but rather that the OP couldn't authenticate with that username.

Comment: @TheSpurg Allright :-) I've used it for years as well, and you are right about HTTPS being available for pushing, I wasn't aware of that. But for *ssh*, you definitely authenticate as user *git*.

Comment: @Kenney ahh I see what you meant now. Yes, that's the convention with using a git server over ssh. There's a system user called `git` that manages the git server, but it uses SSH as the authentication mechanism. :) Very glad I could understand what you meant. You're right, over SSH you technically are authenticating as the system user `git`